# Find every two (non-overlapping) vowels inbetween consonants

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

> **Task** 
>    You are given a string . It consists of alphanumeric characters, spaces and symbols(+,-). 
>    Your task is to find all the substrings of the origina string that contain two or more vowels. 
>    Also, these substrings must lie in between consonants and should contain vowels only.
>
> **Input Format:** a single line of input containing string .
>
> **Output Format:** print the matched substrings in their order of occurrence on separate
>   lines.   If no match is found, print -1.
>
> **Sample Input:**
>   `rabcdeefgyYhFjkIoomnpOeorteeeeet`
>
> **Sample Output:**
>
> `ee`
>   `Ioo`
>   `Oeo`
>   `eeeee`

---

The challenge above was taken from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/re-findall-re-finditer

The following code passes all the test cases:

```
import re

sol = re.findall(r"[^aiueo]([aiueoAIUEO]{2,})(?=[^aiueo])", input())

if sol:
    for s in sol:
        print(s)
else:
    print(-1)
```

The following doesn't.

```
import re

sol = re.findall(r"[^aiueo]([aiueoAIUEO]{2,})[^aiueo]", input())

if sol:
    for s in sol:
        print(s)
else:
    print(-1)
```

The only difference beteen them is the final bit of the regex. I can't understand why the second code fails. I would argue that `?=` is useless because by grouping `[aiueoAIUEO]{2,}` I'm already excluding it from capture, but obviously I'm wrong and I can't tell why.

Any help?

Comment: Try `moomoom` with both approaches :) And both aren't entirely correct, as `[^aeiou]` would allow spaces, uppercase vowels and special symbols instead of explicitly consonants.

Comment: @SebastianProske I thought of excluding the upper case vowels, but forgot. Regarding the spaces and other symbols, I simply failed (and so did the choice of test cases, apparently). Thank you very much. I tested `moomoom` and see what you mean but fail to understand why the bootom code fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lookahead approach allows the consonant that ends one sequence of vowels to start the next sequence, whereas the non-lookahead approach requires at least two consonants between those sequences (one to end a sequence, another to start the next, as both are matched).

See

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'[^aiueo]([aiueoAIUEO]{2,})(?=[^aiueo])', 'moomoom'))
print(re.findall(r'[^aiueo]([aiueoAIUEO]{2,})[^aiueo]', 'moomoom'))
```

Which will output

```
['oo', 'oo']
['oo']
```

https://ideone.com/2Wn1TS

To be a bit picky, both attempts aren't correct regarding your problem description. They allow for uppercase vowels, spaces and symbols to be separators. You might want to use `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` instead of `[^aeiou]` and use `flags=re.I`

Comment: To expand on this, `re.findall` finds non-overlapping matches.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was missing, From the official documentation: (?=`...`) Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'. I was missing the "doesn't consume any of the string" bit, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that doesn't require using the special () characters for grouping, relying instead on a "positive lookbehind assertion" with (?<=...) RE syntax:

```
import re
sol=re.findall(r"(?<=[QWRTYPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm])[AEIOUaeiou]{2,}(?=[QWRTYPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm])", input())
if sol:
    print(*sol, sep="\n")
else:
    print(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.IGNORECASE` our `re.I` flag to ignore case sensitivity. Also, you can avoid vowels, digits from alphanumeric characters and space, `+` and `-` characters mentioned in the problem.

```
import re

vowels = re.findall(r"[^aeiou\d\s+-]([aeiou]{2,})(?=[^aeiou\d\s+-])", input(), re.I)
if len(vowels):
    for vowel in vowels:
        print(vowel)
else:
    print("-1")
```